# Wordpress, Widget Info de Contato & Mapa (jetpack)

Tags: wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress, widget

Preciso corrigir um erro dentro do wordpress, neste momento eu tenho instalado o theme `Flat Bootstrap`,e o mesmo não tem como opção o `Widget Info` de **Contato & Mapa**, esse eu baixei pelo `JetPack`, porem tive que alterar um código para funcionar o `UTF-8` pois os caracteres estavam incorretos, acentos onde não existem etc..

Fiz a seguinte alteração;

```
Pasta/wp-contents/themes/flat-bootstrap/inc/theme-function.php
```

Alterei conforme o curso ensina-rá e por um código

Os caracteres funcionarão e esta tudo correto, porem verifiquei que as minhas fotos do slide sumiram e somente ficou as frase.

Refiz todos os passos e ainda continua o mesmo erro, retirei o widget e as imagens não voltaram, o que devo fazer?

No console está apontando um erro no css.

O site é https://unpraising-runway.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite,

Já olhou o console do navegador e o log do apache para verificar se está sinalizando algo ?

É um pouco complicado e ajudar sem ver o código, mais da um f12 e olha no console se tem algum erro na hora do js gerar o slide.

Dúvidas estou à disposição.

Comment: Eu abri o console no Mozilla, deu esta mensagem /  Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://stats.wp.com/e-201835.js”. O que poderia ser?